# "'Serial' does not name a type" error

Tags: serial, programming

I'm getting a `"'Serial' does not name a type"` error when this program is compiled. I need for the 8 channels of voltage to be displayed. I'm sure it's a simple fix, however I'm still learning Arduino programming. I thank you for your help.

```
int pin_Out_S0 = 8;
int pin_Out_S1 = 9;
int pin_Out_S2 = 10;
int pin_In_Mux1 = A0;
int Mux1_State[8] = {0};
//float Mux1_State[i] =0;
int RawValue=0;
float Voltage = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_Out_S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_Out_S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin_In_Mux1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 RawValue = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
 Voltage = (RawValue * 5.0) / 1024; //scale the ADC
  updateMux1();
  //Serial.println(Mux1_State);
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    if(i == 7) {
      Serial.println(Mux1_State[i]);
    } else {
      Serial.print(Mux1_State[i]);
      Serial.print(",");
      //vout = (value * 5.0) / 1024.0;
    }
  }
}

void updateMux1 () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S0, HIGH && (i & B00000001));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S1, HIGH && (i & B00000010));
    digitalWrite(pin_Out_S2, HIGH && (i & B00000100));
    Mux1_State[i] = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
  }
}
Serial.print("Raw  Value = " );
Serial.print(RawValue);
```

Comment: Tom, StackExchange has got built-in code formatting and syntax colorization.  Paste raw code, select it in the editor, click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Things like `pin_Out_S0` need to be declared, otherwise they will generate error messages.

Answer (score 10):

Your last two lines are not in any function. This confuses the compiler. You need to move those two statements inside a function.

Because those statements refer to `RawValue`, I'm guessing you want to put them in `loop()`, where RawValue is being updated.

Also, remember that the IDE will tell you on which line the error is, which is helpful when debugging compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please put these lines inside the loop() function block:

```
Serial.print("Raw  Value = " );
Serial.print(RawValue);
```

Should look something like:

```
void loop() {
 RawValue = analogRead(pin_In_Mux1);
 Voltage = (RawValue * 5.0) / 1024; //scale the ADC
  updateMux1();
  //Serial.println(Mux1_State);
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    if(i == 7) {
      Serial.println(Mux1_State[i]);
    } else {
      Serial.print(Mux1_State[i]);
      Serial.print(",");
      //vout = (value * 5.0) / 1024.0;
    }
  }
  Serial.print("Raw  Value = " );
  Serial.print(RawValue); 
}
```

That should at least remove the first issue with your code.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers by Mikael and Uint, everything needs to be inside {curly braces} otherwise the IDE does not know where it belongs. If you didn't want the last 2 lines in your loop segment you could put them in a separate `void xxxx ()` section to be called when the time is right (by using an ISR with an `enableinterrupt` function for example).